# Jekyll App - Clear cache with Heroku

Tags: javascript, css, caching, heroku, jekyll

I'm building a static website with Jekyll.
My app is deployed on Heroku, everything works well.
But when I push some CSS/JS on Heroku, modifications are not applied... BUT they are perfectly well applied when I go incognito mode. So I think it must be a cache problem... I tried this tutorial:

https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache

But didn't work...

Does somebody know what can be the problem et how can I fix it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache-bust your resources.

Add a query string with a changing Jekyll variable like site.time to the end of each asset you want to cache bust.  That way, every time your site rebuilds, your resources will have an updated timestamp at the end that will force your browser to redownload your resources.

i.e. something like:

```
"https://siteurl.com/js/main.js?{{site.time | date: '%s%N'}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try ! This morning I checked again. This time Chrome is displaying the correct website.

Comment: @Seybol probably because your cache expired.